# Counting the number of 7 character words in a file that start with tree and do not end in u or v

Tags: unix

I'm trying to count the number of 7 character words in a file that start with tree and do not end in u or v. I know how to specify the begin with tree and end in u or v condition in cat, but I'm not sure how to identify exactly 7 words or enter the conditions using wc. My pathname is /users/file1.txt.

This is the valid cat command(missing number of 7 character words)

```
  cat /users/file1.txt | grep ^tree.*[!uv]
```

Below is the invalid wc command(missing number of 7 character words)

```
  wc - w /users/file1.txt | grep ^tree.*[!uv]
```

Comment: Is it a requirement to use `wc` somewhere in the solution?

Comment: In order to count the words, yes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using `grep` and `wc`:

```
# echo the file       # filter files       # grep EXACT words     # count
cat  /users/file1.txt | grep ^tree.*[^u^v] | grep -o '[^\ ]\{7\}' | wc -w
```

**Pipe walkthrough:**

Echo content of the source file:

```
cat  /users/file1.txt
```

Pass only files starting with "tree" and not ending with either "u" or "v":

```
grep ^tree.*[^u^v]
```

Forward any word that is composed of 7 non-spaces (if you want only letters use `[a-zA-Z]` instead of `[^\ ]`):

```
grep -o '[^\ ]\{7\}'
```

Count the words that made it here:

```
wc -w
```

---

Here is one other way using pretty basic `bash`:

```
count=0

for word in $(cat f.py)
do
    if [ 7 -eq ${#word} ]
    then
        count=$((count+1))
    fi
done

echo $count
```

Or in a single line:

```
count=0; for word in $(cat f.py); do if [ 7 -eq ${#word} ]; then count=$((count+1)); fi; done; echo $count
```

You may want to remove dots and commas from `word`.

Comment: The first example does not seem to pick up only 7-character words.

Comment: @maxwellb you're right I just checked it and got all the words when i should only be getting 5 words

Comment: It works on my test file, what did you try?  I'll add an explanation of my motives for each part in the pipe.

Answer (score 0):

`sed -e 's/%//g' -e 's/\btree..[^uv]\b/%/g' -e 's/[^%]//g' -e 's/%/word /g' /users/file1.txt | wc -w`

1. Don't let anyone steal our token.
2. Give us a token for what we want to count; match word boundaries to count to 7, negate match character in (u,v).
3. Get rid of everything else.
4. Turn our token into a friendly word plus a space.
5. Count 'em.

Answer (score 0):

Do you like perl? Here a one-liner:

```
cat /users/file1.txt | perl -lne 'if (/^(tree)(.{4}$)(?<![uv])/) { print $_ }'
```

Answer (score 0):

Reut's answer is very close.

But this will get you where you need:

```
cat /users/file1.txt | grep -wo 'tree..[^uv]' | wc -l
```

- `-w` will get exact word matches
- see that I ditched the `.*` and specified `..` instead, as the total number of characters matched is 7
- I also got rid of the `^tree` so you can also match words that aren't at the beginning of the line.